# Calculate result based on percentage in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to calculate the following in Powershell

```
$x = 100
$y = 25
result = x * y%
```

Should be really simple, but I can't seem to come up with the right way to calculate the correct result in Powershell

Comment: What does `$x` and `$y` represent? Do you want to calculate 25% of 100 (i.e. 25% of 100 = 25 or 25% of 200 = 50)?

Comment: $x = a number and $y is a percentage. So 25% of 100

Answer (score 7):

Divide by 100 to get the percentage:

```
$x = 100
$y = 25
$result = $x * ($y / 100)
```

Comment: So there is no standard operator for this in PowerShell? Maybe I try to make it more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Correct, there's no operator/method (as far as I know) for converting a number in to a percentage.

Comment: @MisterIks Super curious, is this a common standard operator in any other programming language you're familiar with?